# BigQueryHook job failing with Error: 7916072

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-composer

I am using the BigQueryHook to run a stored procedure in a custom Airflow sensor. It was working perfectly last night, I updated something in the sensor code (unrelated to BQ hook) and all of the sudden it stopped working. When I run the procedure from the UI it succeeds.

Here is the query being run:

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE saleExists BOOL;
  CALL project.exists("US", DATE "2019-2-1", saleExists);
  SELECT saleExists;
END
```

Here is the error:

```
 {'reason': 'invalidQuery', 'location': 'query', 'message': 'domain: "cloud.helix.ErrorDomain" code: "INTERNAL_ERROR" argument: "Error: 7916072" debug_info: "[METADATA_ERROR] Spanner exception: generic::INVALID_ARGUMENT: Name determinism_level not found inside t [at 1:304]\\n...t.details, t.signature, t.non_query_properties, t.determinism_level FROM A...\\n                                                     ^, Reason: code=METADATA_ERROR message=Spanner exception: generic::INVALID_ARGUMENT: Name determinism_level not found inside t [at 1:304]\\n...t.details, t.signature, t.non_query_properties, t.determinism_level FROM A...\\n                                                     ^ debug=Spanner exception: generic::INVALID_ARGUMENT: Name determinism_level not found inside t [at 1:304]\\n...t.details, t.signature, t.non_query_properties, t.determinism_level FROM A...\\n                                                     ^ errorProto=domain: \\"cloud.helix.ErrorDomain\\"\\ncode: \\"INTERNAL_ERROR\\"\\nargument: \\"Error: 7916072\\"\\ndebug_info: \\"Spanner exception: generic::INVALID_ARGUMENT: Name determinism_level not found inside t [at 1:304]\\\\n...t.details, t.signature, t.non_query_properties, t.determinism_level FROM A...\\\\n                                                     ^\\"\\n\\n\\tat com.google.cloud.helix.common.Exceptions.getInternalExceptionNoHash(Exceptions.java:1390)\\n\\tat com.google.cloud.helix.common.Exceptions.getInternalException(Exceptions.java:1382)\\n\\tat com.google.cloud.helix.common.Exceptions.getInternalException(Exceptions.java:1365)\\n\\tat com.google.cloud.helix.common.Exceptions.access$200(Exceptions.java:92)\\n\\tat com.google.cloud.helix.common.Exceptions$Internal.internalError(Exceptions.java:1023)\\n\\tat com.google.cloud.helix.server.metadata.persistence.SpannerUtil.toHelixException(SpannerUtil.java:399)\\n\\tat com.google.cloud.helix.server.metadata.persistence.SpannerUtil.toHelixException(SpannerUtil.java:373)\\n\\tat com.google.cloud.helix.server.metadata.persistence.AbstractSpannerDao$RowCursorIterator.computeNext(AbstractSpannerDao.java:456)\\n\\tat com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:141)\\n\\tat com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:136)\\n\\tat java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:1811)\\n\\tat java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)\\n\\tat java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498)\\n\\tat java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)\\n\\tat java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)\\n\\tat java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)\\n\\tat java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)\\n\\tat java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)\\n\\tat com.google.cloud.helix.server.metadata.persistence.SpannerRoutineDao.getActiveRoutine(SpannerRoutineDao.java:90)\\n\\tat com.google.cloud.helix.server.routine.RoutineServiceUtil.lambda$authorizeAndLookupRoutine$1(RoutineServiceUtil.java:77)\\n\\tat com.google.cloud.helix.server.metadata.persistence.SpannerTransactionContext$RetryCountingWork.run(SpannerTransactionContext.java:997)\\n\\tat com.google.cloud.helix.server.metadata.persistence.SpannerTransactionContext$Factory.executeWithResultInternal(SpannerTransactionContext.java:835)\\n\\tat com.google.cloud.helix.server.metadata.persistence.SpannerTransactionContext$Factory.executeWithResultInternal(SpannerTransactionContext.java:738)\\n\\tat com.google.cloud.helix.server.metadata.persistence.SpannerTransactionContext$Factory.lambda$executeWithResult$1(SpannerTransactionContext.java:729)\\n\\tat com.google.cloud.helix.server.metadata.persistence.SpannerTransactionContext$Factory.executeWithMonitoring(SpannerTransactionContext.java:937)\\n\\tat com.google.cloud.helix.server.metadata.persistence.SpannerTransactionContext$Factory.executeWithResult(SpannerTransactionContext.java:728)\\n\\tat com.google.cloud.helix.server.routine.RoutineServiceUtil.authorizeAndLookupRoutine(RoutineServiceUtil.java:74)\\n\\tat com.google.cloud.helix.server.rosy.GetRoutineImpl.process(GetRoutineImpl.java:68)\\n\\tat com.google.cloud.helix.server.rosy.AuthorizedStorageStubby.getRoutine(AuthorizedStorageStubby.java:109)\\n\\tat com.google.cloud.helix.proto2.Storage$ServiceParameters$25.handleBlockingRequest(Storage.java:2132)\\n\\tat com.google.cloud.helix.proto2.Storage$ServiceParameters$25.handleBlockingRequest(Storage.java:2130)\\n\\tat com.google.net.rpc3.impl.server.RpcBlockingApplicationHandler.handleRequest(RpcBlockingApplicationHandler.java:28)\\n\\tat com.google.net.rpc3.impl.server.RpcServerInternalContext.runRpcInApplication(RpcServerInternalContext.java:607)\\n\\tat com.google.net.rpc3.impl.server.RpcServerChannel$4.apply(RpcServerChannel.java:975)\\n\\tat com.google.net.rpc3.impl.server.RpcServerChannel$4.apply(RpcServerChannel.java:960)\\n\\tat com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractTransformFuture$TransformFuture.doTransform(AbstractTransformFuture.java:242)\\n\\tat com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractTransformFuture$TransformFuture.doTransform(AbstractTransformFuture.java:232)\\n\\tat com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractTransformFuture.run(AbstractTransformFuture.java:118)\\n\\tat com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:454)\\n\\tat com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:461)\\n\\tat io.grpc.Context.run(Context.java:575)\\n\\tat com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:206)\\n\\tat com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:320)\\n\\tat com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:311)\\n\\tat com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:458)\\n\\tat com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$5$1.run(MoreExecutors.java:1158)\\n\\tat com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:454)\\n\\tat com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:461)\\n\\tat com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:322)\\n\\tat com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:311)\\n\\tat com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:458)\\n\\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\\n\\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\\n\\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\\nCaused by: com.google.spanner.SpannerException: generic::INVALID_ARGUMENT: Name determinism_level not found inside t [at 1:304]\\n...t.details, t.signature, t.non_query_properties, t.determinism_level FROM A...\\n                                                     ^\\n\\tat com.google.spanner.InternalAccess.newSpannerException(InternalAccess.java:120)\\n\\tat com.google.spanner.impl.SpannerExceptionFactory.newExceptionWithStatus(SpannerExceptionFactory.java:57)\\n\\tat com.google.spanner.impl.SpannerExceptionFactory.throwWithStatus(SpannerExceptionFactory.java:53)\\n\\tat com.google.spanner.impl.SpannerExceptionFactory.throwWithStatus(SpannerExceptionFactory.java:48)\\n\\tat com.google.spanner.impl.ThinRowCursor.getNextReadResponse(ThinRowCursor.java:597)\\n\\tat com.google.spanner.impl.ThinRowCursor.tryNextInternal(ThinRowCursor.java:537)\\n\\tat com.google.spanner.impl.ThinRowCursor.next(ThinRowCursor.java:330)\\n\\tat com.google.cloud.helix.server.metadata.persistence.AbstractSpannerDao$RowCursorIterator.computeNext(AbstractSpannerDao.java:452)\\n\\t... 46 more\\n" at [3:8]'}. The job was: {'kind': 'bigquery#job', 'etag': '7n4/kLb4tXM1MqNnElC+nw==', 'id': ‘MYJOBID’, 'selfLink': 'https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/myproject/jobs/job_UcVj-3q1s80vpN7jO3uzrsk-P--T?location=US', 'user_email': ‘ouremail’, 'configuration': {'query': {'query': "BEGIN\n  DECLARE exists BOOL;\n  CALL Dataset.StoredProcedure(inputs…, exists);\n  SELECT exists;\nEND", 'priority': 'INTERACTIVE', 'useLegacySql': False}, 'jobType': 'QUERY'}, 'jobReference': {—taking this out for private info reasons—}, 'statistics': {'creationTime': '1571764174495', 'startTime': '1571764174576', 'endTime': '1571764175461', 'query': {'statementType': 'SCRIPT'}}, 'status': {'errorResult': {'reason': 'invalidQuery', 'location': 'query', 'message': 'domain: "cloud.helix.ErrorDomain" code: "INTERNAL_ERROR" argument: "Error: 7916072" debug_info: "[METADATA_ERROR] Spanner exception: generic::INVALID_ARGUMENT: Name determinism_level not found inside t [at 1:304]\\n...t.details, t.signature, t.non_query_properties, t.determinism_level FROM A...\\n                                                     ^, Reason: code=METADATA_ERROR message=Spanner exception: generic::INVALID_ARGUMENT: Name determinism_level not found inside t [at 1:304]\\n...t.details, t.signature, t.non_query_properties, t.determinism_level FROM A...\\n                                                     ^ debug=Spanner exception: generic::INVALID_ARGUMENT: Name determinism_level not found inside t [at 1:304]\\n...t.details, t.signature, t.non_query_properties, t.determinism_level FROM A...\\n                                                     ^ errorProto=domain: \\"cloud.helix.ErrorDomain\\"\\ncode: \\"INTERNAL_ERROR\\"\\nargument: \\"Error: 7916072\\"\\ndebug_info: \\"Spanner exception: generic::INVALID_ARGUMENT: Name determinism_level not found inside t [at 1:304]\\\\n...t.details, t.signature, t.non_query_properties, t.determinism_level FROM A...\\\\n                                                     ^\\"\\n\\n\\tat com.google.cloud.helix.common.Exceptions.getInternalExceptionNoHash(Exceptions.java:1390)\\n\\tat com.google.cloud.helix.common.Exceptions.getInternalException(Exceptions.java:1382)\\n\\tat com.google.cloud.helix.common.Exceptions.getInternalException(Exceptions.java:1365)\\n\\tat com.google.cloud.helix.common.Exceptions.access$200(Exceptions.java:92)\\n\\tat com.google.cloud.helix.common.Exceptions$Internal.internalError(Exceptions.java:1023)\\n\\tat com.google.cloud.helix.server.metadata.persistence.SpannerUtil.toHelixException(SpannerUtil.java:399)\\n\\tat com.google.cloud.helix.server.metadata.persistence.SpannerUtil.toHelixException(SpannerUtil.java:373)\\n\\tat com.google.cloud.helix.server.metadata.persistence.AbstractSpannerDao$RowCursorIterator.computeNext(AbstractSpannerDao.java:456)\\n\\tat com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:141)\\n\\tat com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:136)\\n\\tat java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:1811)\\n\\tat java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)\\n\\tat java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498)\\n\\tat java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)\\n\\tat java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)\\n\\tat java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)\\n\\tat java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)\\n\\tat java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)\\n\\tat com.google.cloud.helix.server.metadata.persistence.SpannerRoutineDao.getActiveRoutine(SpannerRoutineDao.java:90)\\n\\tat com.google.cloud.helix.server.routine.RoutineServiceUtil.lambda$authorizeAndLookupRoutine$1(RoutineServiceUtil.java:77)\\n\\tat com.google.cloud.helix.server.metadata.persistence.SpannerTransactionContext$RetryCountingWork.run(SpannerTransactionContext.java:997)\\n\\tat com.google.cloud.helix.server.metadata.persistence.SpannerTransactionContext$Factory.executeWithResultInternal(SpannerTransactionContext.java:835)\\n\\tat com.google.cloud.helix.server.metadata.persistence.SpannerTransactionContext$Factory.executeWithResultInternal(SpannerTransactionContext.java:738)\\n\\tat com.google.cloud.helix.server.metadata.persistence.SpannerTransactionContext$Factory.lambda$executeWithResult$1(SpannerTransactionContext.java:729)\\n\\tat com.google.cloud.helix.server.metadata.persistence.SpannerTransactionContext$Factory.executeWithMonitoring(SpannerTransactionContext.java:937)\\n\\tat com.google.cloud.helix.server.metadata.persistence.SpannerTransactionContext$Factory.executeWithResult(SpannerTransactionContext.java:728)\\n\\tat com.google.cloud.helix.server.routine.RoutineServiceUtil.authorizeAndLookupRoutine(RoutineServiceUtil.java:74)\\n\\tat com.google.cloud.helix.server.rosy.GetRoutineImpl.process(GetRoutineImpl.java:68)\\n\\tat com.google.cloud.helix.server.rosy.AuthorizedStorageStubby.getRoutine(AuthorizedStorageStubby.java:109)\\n\\tat com.google.cloud.helix.proto2.Storage$ServiceParameters$25.handleBlockingRequest(Storage.java:2132)\\n\\tat com.google.cloud.helix.proto2.Storage$ServiceParameters$25.handleBlockingRequest(Storage.java:2130)\\n\\tat com.google.net.rpc3.impl.server.RpcBlockingApplicationHandler.handleRequest(RpcBlockingApplicationHandler.java:28)\\n\\tat com.google.net.rpc3.impl.server.RpcServerInternalContext.runRpcInApplication(RpcServerInternalContext.java:607)\\n\\tat com.google.net.rpc3.impl.server.RpcServerChannel$4.apply(RpcServerChannel.java:975)\\n\\tat com.google.net.rpc3.impl.server.RpcServerChannel$4.apply(RpcServerChannel.java:960)\\n\\tat com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractTransformFuture$TransformFuture.doTransform(AbstractTransformFuture.java:242)\\n\\tat com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractTransformFuture$TransformFuture.doTransform(AbstractTransformFuture.java:232)\\n\\tat com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractTransformFuture.run(AbstractTransformFuture.java:118)\\n\\tat com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:454)\\n\\tat com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:461)\\n\\tat io.grpc.Context.run(Context.java:575)\\n\\tat com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:206)\\n\\tat com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:320)\\n\\tat com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:311)\\n\\tat com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:458)\\n\\tat com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$5$1.run(MoreExecutors.java:1158)\\n\\tat com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:454)\\n\\tat com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:461)\\n\\tat com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:322)\\n\\tat com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:311)\\n\\tat com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:458)\\n\\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\\n\\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\\n\\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\\nCaused by: com.google.spanner.SpannerException: generic::INVALID_ARGUMENT: Name determinism_level not found inside t [at 1:304]\\n...t.details, t.signature, t.non_query_properties, t.determinism_level FROM A...\\n                                                     ^\\n\\tat com.google.spanner.InternalAccess.newSpannerException(InternalAccess.java:120)\\n\\tat com.google.spanner.impl.SpannerExceptionFactory.newExceptionWithStatus(SpannerExceptionFactory.java:57)\\n\\tat com.google.spanner.impl.SpannerExceptionFactory.throwWithStatus(SpannerExceptionFactory.java:53)\\n\\tat com.google.spanner.impl.SpannerExceptionFactory.throwWithStatus(SpannerExceptionFactory.java:48)\\n\\tat com.google.spanner.impl.ThinRowCursor.getNextReadResponse(ThinRowCursor.java:597)\\n\\tat com.google.spanner.impl.ThinRowCursor.tryNextInternal(ThinRowCursor.java:537)\\n\\tat com.google.spanner.impl.ThinRowCursor.next(ThinRowCursor.java:330)\\n\\tat com.google.cloud.helix.server.metadata.persistence.AbstractSpannerDao$RowCursorIterator.computeNext(AbstractSpannerDao.java:452)\\n\\t... 46 more\\n" at [3:8]'}, 'state': 'DONE'}
```

To highlight, it was working last night and nothing changed with the query so not sure why it is failing. When I look in the console it is also showing as failing, but when I click on the job and re-run it myself it succeeds

Any insight on this error? have a deadline in a few hours and this just stopped working, couldn't find any previous question or mentions of this error message

Comment: CALL project.exists("US", DATE "2019-2-1", **saleExists**);  ?

Comment: Sorry, I was just doing a find and replace to get my personal project info out - the actual query runs fine and there aren't syntax errors, it fails when it is run from Bigqueryhook but if I click on the job failed job and re-run it it succeeds. That was just an error copy and pasting my project data out

Comment: You have to create a bug on BigQuery https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers. A few hours might not be sufficient to get it resolved though.

Comment: Why would it stop working if it was working last night?

Comment: I don't know... Could you try to create another procedure to see if you will have same issue?

Comment: Same issue, but weird if I set the number of retries to 2 it works

Comment: Submitted a bug report, thanks for your help. Will close this out

Comment: Kidding it is not working anymore at all

Comment: the fix may take a while, you may unblock yourself by putting the procedure body in the query.